# What order do I do projects on my kitchen remodel

Tags: kitchens, remodeling

I am refinishing cabinets, replacing counters, replacing back splash, floors and appliances.  What order should I do the jobs in?

Answer (score 4):

Floors, cabinets, counters, backsplash, appliances. Cabinets could also be done first, especially if you're not refinishing them in place.

The idea is to do projects earlier which do not depend on anything else, or when those dependencies have already been completed. Backsplash depends on the counters, so the counters must be done first. Counters depend on having cabinets in place on which to install the counter, so the cabinets must be done first. Appliances are finishes, so are done last.

Answer (score 1):

My experience old floor coverings are removed first and new floor is installed last. Previous poster was spot on with the other elements. You don't want to knick your newly finished cabinets trying to get up old tile, and you don't want to damage the new stuff you are putting down by dripping stain or dropping something heavy on it.